# Should I write down all four addresses on a UK Landing Card?

Tags: uk, hotels, borders, customs-and-immigration

If I am staying at several (say, 4) different hotels across the country during my trip, should I list them all on the landing card under the field "**Contact address in the UK (in full)**"?

Many discussions online seem to point out that only the address during the first night is of importance, but is that practice acceptable if I am staying at the said place only for the first night but somewhere entirely different for the next 10 nights?

I suppose they would like to see all addresses according to a [recent account by an ex-Home Office worker](https://www.ft.com/content/e7849a0c-7e85-11e7-9108-edda0bcbc928):

> "**Landing cards were a “useful intelligence tool”, David Wood, former Home Office director-general of immigration enforcement, told The Times. “We could access them to find out where someone was staying or where they had stayed if we were carrying out an investigation.**”"

A picture of the landing card can be seen [here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-83z1ycgmW_4/T79nxELHc7I/AAAAAAAADRQ/BwkeFe3BBqA/s1600/uk+landing+card.JPG)

[image: Photo of UK Landing Card]

Answer (score 3):

**All that is required is the first address**.  The primary reason this is asked is that so they can check that you're actually planning to stay where you claim you're staying, although in practice checks are rare.

(No, I don't have a UK-specific reference, but this is the standard worldwide and [the UK is planning to scrap the cards soon](http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/837384/home-office-landing-cards-scrapped-non-eu-citizens-welcome-security-checks) anyway.)